# Passage Vs Passage

Tags: vocabulaire

The word Passage (a movement in dressage) has a different meaning and pronunciation to the word Passage (taking a trip or tunnel).

Can this pronunciation difference be highlighted by use of a French accent mark?

Comment: Where have you seen they have different pronunciation?

Comment: @Toto: I think the OP refers to the English pronunciation.

Comment: Welcome to the site, is that horseback riding or dogs or what? Thank you!

Comment: There aren't any accent marks on *passage* in French. So, no.

Answer (score 4):

In French, every instance of "passage" has the exact same pronunciation. There are more than two.

Answer (score 3):

You can't write accents in French if they're not initially part of the word - it's a spelling error.

In French, both meanings of the word *passage* you're referring to are written and pronunciated identically.